# Why doesn't this code work if we change the function order?

Tags: jquery

**If I have the code like this, the sliders will NOT slide:**

```
var $root = $('html, body');
$('.main-menu a').each(function () {
    // capture the offset on init not click
    var that = $(this),
        offset = $(that.attr('href')).offset().top - $('nav.main-menu').height() + 1;
    // then use that offset, so we are not querying for id on each click
    that.click(function () {
        $root.animate({
            scrollTop: offset
        }, 2000);
    });
});

$('.cycle-container').each(function () {
    $(this).cycle({
        fx: 'scrollLeft',
        speed: 'slow',
        timeout: 0,
        next: this
    });
});
```

If I change it to this: It works. :s

```
$('.cycle-container').each(function () {
    $(this).cycle({
        fx: 'scrollLeft',
        speed: 'slow',
        timeout: 0,
        next: this
    });
});

var $root = $('html, body');
$('.main-menu a').each(function () {
    // capture the offset on init not click
    var that = $(this),
        offset = $(that.attr('href')).offset().top - $('nav.main-menu').height() + 1;
    // then use that offset, so we are not querying for id on each click
    that.click(function () {
        $root.animate({
            scrollTop: offset
        }, 2000);
    });
});
```

I'm that newbie on js in general. I've just switch the order. Any reason or idea about why will this order makes the code to work, and the first order doesn't?

By doesn't work, I mean, I click on the slider and it doesn't slide.

I go to **firebug**, I click **console**, and then **ALL**, and I see:

```
TypeError: d.detachEvent is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

if ( event.target.nodeType === 3 ) {
```

**And**

```
"CSS Usage: initializing extensions" TypeError: $(...).offset(...) is undefined [Break On This Error]   

return event.result;
```

The first of those, is returned by jquery1.9.1 himself, but I didn't touch it.

The html structure:

```
<div class="cycle-container">
    <div id="row-slide2">
        <section id="slide2">
             <h1>bla bla</h1>

            <p>ble ble ble</p>
        </section>
    </div>
    <div id="row-slide2-1">
        <section id="slide2-1">
             <h1>bli bli</h1>

            <div class="table">
                <div class="column">
                     <h2>blo blo</h2>

                    <p>blu blu</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

*Jquery 1.9.1;*

*Waypoints plugin;*

*Cycle Plugin;*

**UPDATE**
If I change the code to:

```
var that   = $(this);
var offset = $(that.attr('href')).offset().top-$('nav.main-menu').height()+1;
```

Instead of:

```
var that   = $(this),
    offset = $(that.attr('href')).offset().top-$('nav.main-menu').height()+1;
```

Actually, in works with either order. :S

The only issue, being that, the code will now make an undesirable blink.
AND, this error still occurs on console:

```
TypeError: $(...).offset(...) is undefined
[Break On This Error]   

var offset = $(that.attr('href')).offset().top-$('nav.main-menu').height()+1;
```

Please check the jsfiddle accordingly:
http://jsfiddle.net/talofo/Hq9NL/2/

*A note about this fiddle:*
The fiddle is a more or less representation of my local code. However, since the beginning, the *local* code order did matter, and on *fiddle* it never matter, and it always work.

Comment: It would help to know which plugins you're using and what the HTML structure is.

Comment: @Kolink - thanks for pointing that out, since the errors are not trow at my face each time they occur like, for example with E_ALL on php, I guess I tend to forget a lot to see the console. I've updated my question with that.

Comment: @MEM there is not specify  line `if ( event.target.nodeType === 3 ) {` in your code. can you add that code also.

Comment: If I make a fiddle of it, this works with any order. :(( So no point for making a fiddle I guess. :s ?

Comment: @BrokenHeartღ Just updated my question accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: @MEM If it works fine in a fiddle that suggests that there is some other code on your site interfering with the events you are attaching or detaching.

Comment: @Chris - That I'm almost sure is true. And believe me, I would love to know what that "something" is. I got only symptoms for now. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I end up dropping the all offset thing:

I just did:

```
var $root = $('html, body');

$('.main-menu a').click(function() {
 $root.animate({
  scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top-$('nav.main-menu').height()+1
 }, 2000
);

return false;
});
```

And changed the html structure.
So, now the offset is set onclick.

And the waypoint call I changed to:

```
$('#container>div').each(function()
```

Thanks for your time towards this. And sorry for being so specific. I will preserve this, because, for some reason someone may find it useful and, with me, notice that the issue of order may rely on console errors, or bad html structure.